# using Azure CDN with static website but still slow

Tags: azure

I am using Azure CDN with my static website (video-based training ) that I host on  my storage account but the website still slow when loading.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. can you provide more details like size of your video files, which product type under CDN ? [ CDN has Standard from MS, Standard from Akamai, Std from Verizon, and Premium from Verizon]

Comment: The size of my video is around 50 MB to 250 MP. The CDN type is Standard from MS.         THANKS

Comment: I found that the chunked loading caused an speed issue - can't explain why. Worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a screenshot of the network view of the developer toolbox? Its bit hard to just guess what might be slow.

But in general, a CDN is a great way to distribute your content.
**BUT** the load latency will also depend on the distance to the nearest Point of content and the cache rate.

A file needs to be cached by the CDN endpoint before you will see an improvement. So, the "first" load will always be slow as it comes directly from the source.

If compression is not configured for static assets, maybe consider enabling compression as this could further reduce the size of assets which needs to be transported to the client.

Also, if you are dealing with large files like videos. There might be additional configuration required:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-media-streaming-optimization
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-large-file-optimization

Comment: Thank you Julian, very useful information.